# Visibility fadeout and fade in infinite loop

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have some `Grid` with some element inside and I want to add it some fade in fade out effect with `Visibility` property in infinite loop base on some `bool` `property`.
This is what I have tried:

```
<Grid.Style>
   <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                      From="0.0" 
                                      To="1.0"                                                                                    
                                      Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

Currently I cannot see my `Grid` at all.

Comment: You do not see your `Grid`, because you set `Opacity` to `0` initially, set it to `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your style:

- You do not see the `Grid`, because you set the initial `Opacity` to `0`.
- You can remove both of your `Setter`s, because those are the default values
- Making the trigger dependent on `Visibility` does not work, because when it is set to `Collapsed`, the `Grid` is already invisible, so the animation is not even visible.
- There is no exit action to make the `Grid` fade in again.

You could solve the issues by exposing a property (here `MyAnimationTriggerProperty`) that you use as trigger for the animation. Depending o your actual application this could also be the `IsChecked` state of another control. Then you can add an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to set the `Visibility` at the end of the animation.

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyAnimationTriggerProperty}" Value="False">
         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                               From="1.0" 
                                               To="0.0"                                                                                    
                                               Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
         <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                               From="0.0" 
                                               To="1.0"                                                                                    
                                               Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```